# how to switch this json data clearly and fast

Tags: javascript

```
const data = [
    {
      month:'2019-01',
      list:[
        {name:'china',share:98},
        {name:'japan',share:89},
        {name:'others',share:45},
      ]
    },
    {
      month:'2019-02',
      list:[
        {name:'china',share:34},
        {name:'usa',share:56},
        {name:'others',share:33},
      ]
    }
  ]
```

switch to this json

```
[
  ['month','2019-01','2019-02'],
  ['china',98,34],
  ['japan',89,0],
  ['usa',0,56],
  ['others',45,33],
]
```

when this month is not this name, this share should be 0.like `['usa',0,56],`

i thought take out all the countries,and map it

```
const ALL = [
    ...new Set(
      data &&
        data
          .map(i => i.list)
          .flat(1)
          .map(j => j.name)
    ),
  ];
```

and map ALL map data map data.list

```
const ALL = [
    ...new Set(
      data &&
        data
          .map(i => i.list)
          .flat(1)
          .map(j => j.name)
    ),
  ];
```

how to turn it be easy and control clean code

Comment: What's the difference between the first `ALL` and the second one?

Comment: It should be `.map(i=>i.list.map(j=>j.name)).flat()`